# Is 'zfs send' a safe read only command?

Tags: security, sudo, zfs

I would allow **server A** to be backed up by **server B**, without allowing any server to modify the other server.

non-root user zfsbackup @ **server A** is allowed to use only  `zfs send`:

```
# serverA: /etc/sudoers.d/zfsbackup 

zfsbackup ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/zfs send *
```

Which makes it possible for **server B** to perform a backup of **server A** like this:

```
root@serverB~:# ssh zfsbackup@serverA sudo zfs send -i tank/vol@yesterday tank/vol@today | zfs receive tank/vol
```

Question is:

> Can a malicious user do any damage using the `zfs send *` command? Or is this command completely read only?

Comment: I understand that zfs delegation with `zfs allow` command is the preferred way to do this, but it is not available in ZoL 0.6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a malicious user do any damage using the zfs send * command? Or is this command completely read only?

While the `zfs send` command doesn't modify the contents of the file-system, it's still possible for a malicious user to use it to DoS your system by saturating the file-system and sometimes the network, depending on how evil they choose to be.